# SVN diff all strings.xml files in android project between 2 revisions

Tags: android, svn, diff

Is there a way to compare all strings.xml files in my android project between 2 revisions in SVN?

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I don't know much about android so I'm not entirely clear by what you mean by "all strings.xml files in my android project."

But you should just be able to do:

```
svn diff -rM:N file1 file2 file3 ...
```

You could do something like this if you have multiple strings.xml files (assuming a unix OS):

```
svn diff -rM:N `find . -name strings.xml`
```

In both of the above examples -rM:N specifies the range you want to selec to compare.  M is the older revision and N is the newer revision (though you can reverse them to get a diff that shows the changes to go back to the older revision).